# how to change file name in makefile rule

Tags: makefile

I have no problem to generate dep with gcc

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -MMD -c $< -o $<
```

right now I change to armcc and it required following option to genreate `.d`, I can run this single command to generate `.d`

```
armcc --md -depend=a.d -c a.c -o a.o
```

How can I adapte armcc to gcc code part? I try below code but doesn't help, it did not generate `.d` file

```
%.o: %.c
    armcc --md -depend=$(patsubst %o, %.d, $@) -c @< -o $@
```

**UPDATE**

I use below code from anwser:

```
%.o: %.c
    armcc --md -depend=$(@:%.o=%.d) -c @< -o $@
```

and still no `.d` output, I check the console：

```
armcc    -c -o a1.o a1.c
armcc    -c -o a2.o a2.c
armcc    -c -o a3.o a3.c
armcc    -c -o main.o main.c
armlink -o test a1.o a2.o a3.o main.o
```

I found during compile, even my `--md` and `--depend` option not appiled??

Comment: In your `patsubst` you are replacing `%o` with `%.d`, so the result for a file `foo.o` will be that `%` matches `foo.`, not `foo`, and the output will be `foo..d` not `foo.d`.

Comment: Also, I believe that should be a `$<` instead of `@<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%.o: %.c
    armcc --md -depend=$(@:%.o=%.d) -c @< -o $@
```

This will simply tell GNU make to replace `object.o` by `object.d`.

`$@` is your target
`%.o=%.d` returns the *.d name of your object file.

Comment: I try this but still can not, I update my result in my question

Comment: I think your code is correct because I re-write another makefile and it work, I really don't know why in my first makefile, even the compile option is not applied in the rule